# Restoring data from a flashdrive

Tags: usb, data-recovery

Friends, I messed up and formatted a USB flash drive with 51 GB data on it that I need. The drive was formatted in FAT32 and I reformatted it as HFS+ Journaled drive. I tried recovering the partition table with testdisk but didn't manage to, but with photorec I restored the data - it's all in different folders with random file names now. Any tips on how to get it back in a more orderly fashion? I was recommended R-Studio but would like to see if there are any more affordable solutions.

edit: there's a big mix of file types, pdf, image files, ebooks, word docs, mp3, movie files.. anything you can think of probably.

Comment: What kind of data ? For sorting photos [`sort-pictures`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/sort-pictures.1.html) makes a good job.

Comment: @pLumo all kinds: pdfs, ebooks, word docs, movie files, mp3, jpg.. it's all mixed up

Comment: You should first stop using the flash drive before restoring the data from it, which can avoid data overwritten. Then you can try some flashdrive recovery programs, such as Bitwar data recovery, etc, to restore data.